# Why my .bat file for deleting these files does not work?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat file for deleting all the files with the extensions .aux, .log, .gz from a given folder. In the command line window it works but when I run the .bat file nothing happens. I'm getting crazy with it. Can anyone take a look at it:

```
echo off
erase /q "desktop\teste\*.log"
erase /q "desktop\teste\*.gz"
erase /q "desktop\teste\*.aux"
exit
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I don't know much about it but pretty sure "erase" should be "del"...

Comment: I guess both turns out to be equivalent..

Comment: Use full paths. `@del "%userprofile%\desktop\teste\*.log" "%userprofile%\desktop\teste\*.gz" "%userprofile%\desktop\teste\*.aux"`. That is your batch that will always work and is one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you are in the same directory with your bat file as where you are in cmd?

Comment: You solved the problem.. the path wasn't the same.. Thanks =)